# Greek encoding in android with HttpClient

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am trying to download a webpage from my android program. But the webpage is greek(), and i only get ??????? in return.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString(); 
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

The link to the web server is :
http://www.cysms.eu/anagram/android/getWR.php

Can you please help me on how to get the greek text correctly?

Regards,
Nicos

Comment: Post the url so we can have a look.

Comment: What should we see: ΝΕΦΤΑΚΙ or ΜΑΣΟΥΡΙ ? How is it possible that Firefox shows ΝΕΦΤΑΚΙ but going to view source i see ΜΑΣΟΥΡΙ? Can't you make a more realistic page? This no no fun with one word and only one Greek character. Moreover i'ts no valid html page. Please make a decent page.

Comment: Its not about making a more realistic or fun page. That greek word you see there, will be picked up from my android app, and use it as it should!

Comment: Which greek word? Please read what i saw and asked.

Comment: It doesn't matter which word as it is a random word. If you refresh the page you will see different words. Just when i get the words with my android app, i just get ?????? instead of characters

Comment: Make a page which delivers one tekst. Tell what the text is here. How can i check things when i don't know what i should get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webservice has `charset=Windows-1253` and android expects `utf-8`, try convert response from `win1253` to `utf-8`